# How to put variable into cookie?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, cookies

I'd like to put a variable's string into a cookie. (as the content) Currently the cookie does set and the name is username. (That part works) the content from the variable isnt saved in the cookie though. Here's what i have. I have looked at one other similar question and the answer didnt work. Possible because i'm using a string

```
var sharedContent = sharedURL;
var sharedURL = "http://www.example.com/";
function getUrl() {
window.location.href= sharedURL;
createCookie();
}
function createCookie() {
document.cookie = "username="+sharedContent+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2025 13:47:11 UTC; path=/"
}
```

As you may have noticed, i am a bit new to using js.

Html:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a href="https://www.minds.com/newsfeed"><div class="button" onclick="getUrl(); "><img src="icon.png" width="16">Share</div></a>
```

Comment: You need to switch your order of declarations around. Variable definitions do not get hoisted. So sharedURL should be the first var and the second sharedContent Example: https://jsbin.com/zomewucomo/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working perfectly fine if you change variable/function declaration position and changing `;` to `,`

```
var sharedURL = "http://www.example.com/";
var sharedContent = sharedURL;
function createCookie() {
var cookies = "username="+sharedContent+", expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2025 13:47:11 UTC, path=/"
document.cookie = cookies;
}
function getUrl() {
window.location.href= sharedURL;
createCookie();
}
getUrl();
```

Comment: Should the getURL(); at the end be there?

Comment: it is not require but without calling getUrl() function it can't set cookies as code is inside getUrl() function.

Comment: Have you tried testing this? I did and it redirected me to example.com when the page loaded.

Comment: 'window.location.href= sharedURL;' this line in your code is redirecting to example.com, and yes  i have tested code it is setting cookies to browser, you can also check by typing 'document.cookie ' into developer console.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I still need to put the url of the current page into the sharedURL variable. Do you know how to do this without it redirecting?

Comment: You can use ''sharedURL=window.location.href"  ,this will put current page url to sharedUrl variable ,and to stop redirecting remove " 
'window.location.href= sharedURL;" from code.

Answer (score 0):

Call `CreaetCookie()`function before `window.location.href`. I haven't try but it should work.